# Lagrange multiplier with $2$ constraints: $J(x,y,z)=x^2+\frac{y^3}{3}+z$, subject to $x-y+z=0$ and $2x+y=z$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

> $$J(x,y,z)=x^2+\frac{y^3}{3}+z$$ subject to $x-y+z=0$ and $2x+y=z$. Find the stationary points and determine the nature of each one.

---

Attempt:

By using $\nabla J=\lambda \nabla g+\mu \nabla h$ where $g,h$ are the two constaints:

$2x=\lambda+\mu$

$y^2=-\lambda+\mu$

$1=\lambda-\mu$

I don't know how to continue from here because I get $y^2=-1$ from these equations

Comment: Hello. Please, use LaTeX next time.

Comment: Should $J$ be $x^2+y^3+z$ (title) or $x^2+y^2/3+z$ (body)? Update whichever is wrong. The coefficients in your simultaneous equations also have the occasional error.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have stationary points. Let's look at the constraints. We can write them as $$x=0\\y=z$$
If you plug these into the original expression, you would need to minimize $$f(y)=J(0,y,y)=\frac{y^3}3+y$$
Taking the derivative with respect to $y$ and setting it to $0$, you get your expression$$y^2+1=0$$This has no real solutions. This function is monotonically increasing with $y$, and it does not have any stationary point.

Comment: I guess there is something wrong with the problem. A typo maybe.

Comment: It is likely. But if you have the constraints as two planes, it means that the constraint is a line (the intersection of two planes), so you can just plug in the values and check your result.